# <?php echo "HTML" ?>

Tags: php, html

i am new to PHP and i have got an issue with dynamically loaded HTML-content. I've designed a price label, which i want to be stored in one PHP-file, to make changes apply to every position on the website:

```
<?php
$preisschild_a = "<div class="centered"><h3>Komplett ab</h3></div><div class="preisschild redbg"><div class="preis">";

$preis_neo = "1.000,- €";
$preis_vision55 = "1.000,- €";
$preis_vision80 = "1.000,- €";
$preis_pult = "3.699,- €";
$preis_ultra = "1.000,- €";
$preis_beamcase = "1.000,- €";

$preisschild_b = "</div><div class="preis-subline">zzgl. MWST</div></div><div class="centered"><h3>Infos und Bestellung:</h3><span class="rot block"><h3>05252/9778511</h3></span></div><hr>";

?>
```

As you can see, i've cut the whole code into 3 pieces, to assemble it on the website again:

```
<?php echo "$preisschild_a"; ?>
<?php echo "$preis_pult"; ?>
<?php echo "$preisschild_b"; ?>
```

The fact is, that the whole page keeps beeing white. It does not work anyway.

Where's the bug? Thanx in advance!

Comment: parse errors but you're not checking for them http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a `"` character in a string starting with `"` unless you escape it (`\"`).

Re-write them so they look like this:

```
$preisschild_a = '<div class="centered"><h3>Komplett ab</h3></div><div class="preisschild redbg"><div class="prei">';
```

or

```
$preisschild_a = "<div class=\"centered\"><h3>Komplett ab</h3></div><div class=\"preisschild redbg\"><div class=\"prei\">";
```

Make sure to do the same for `$preisschild_b`.

You can also have `"` inside a `'`, but you can't have the same type of quotes unless first escaped with `\`.

Also, to echo variables, you don't have to put them in quotes. eg:

```
<?php echo $preisschild_a; ?>
<?php echo $preis_pult; ?>
<?php echo $preisschild_b; ?>
```

You can put them in double quotes and they will parse normally, but will not do in single quotes.

eg:

```
<?php echo '$test';?> //$test
```

Comment: *"Also, to echo variables, you don't put them in quotes."* - Nota: variables do parse in double quotes, just not single quotes.

Comment: Thanks, will clarify. I had also meant to say you don't *have* to put them in quotes so I'm glad you caught that thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome Alex.

Comment: Maybe also as a smal side notice that you can use shorttags if shorttags are enabled in `php.ini`

Comment: You should use single-quotes around the string and double quotes inside for the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

First you need something like this:

```
<?php
$preisschild_a = "<div class=\"centered\"><h3>Komplett ab</h3></div><div class=\"preisschild redbg\"><div class=\"preis\">";

$preis_neo = "1.000,- €";
$preis_vision55 = "1.000,- €";
$preis_vision80 = "1.000,- €";
$preis_pult = "3.699,- €";
$preis_ultra = "1.000,- €";
$preis_beamcase = "1.000,- €";

$preisschild_b = "</div><div class=\"preis-subline\">zzgl. MWST</div></div><div class=\"centered\"><h3>Infos und Bestellung:</h3><span class=\"rot block\"><h3>05252/9778511</h3></span></div><hr>";

?>
```

And after, when you echo:

```
<?php echo $preisschild_a; ?>
<?php echo $preis_pult; ?>
<?php echo $preisschild_b; ?>
```

(without quotes: " or ')

Comment: *"(without quotes: " or ')"* - why not? Double quotes are fine.

Comment: https://php.net/language.types.string

Answer (score 0):

Mashup with `double` and `single` `quotes`;

Replace all `"` with `'` in all `div elements`

Use this

```
<?php
$preisschild_a = "<div class='centered'><h3>Komplett ab</h3></div><div class='preisschild redbg'><div class='preis'>";

$preis_neo = "1.000,- €";
$preis_vision55 = "1.000,- €";
$preis_vision80 = "1.000,- €";
$preis_pult = "3.699,- €";
$preis_ultra = "1.000,- €";
$preis_beamcase = "1.000,- €";

$preisschild_b = "</div><div class='preis-subline'>zzgl. MWST</div></div><div class='centered'><h3>Infos und Bestellung:</h3><span class='rot block'><h3>05252/9778511</h3></span></div><hr>";

?>
```